# Adding Custom events to caldroid?

Tags: android, events, calendar, android-custom-view

I had been searching for a Calendar view which would allow me to add custom events and Customize it.Currently my app is targeted for all android users using Android Gingerbread and above and caldroid seems to be the best choice.
I can't use ExtendedCalendarView because the min API required for it is 14.

However I've not been able to add custom events to my caldroid fragment and the documentation doesn't seem to help much.
Can somebody help me out with this?

Answer (score 3):

First, create CaldroidSampleCustomAdapter and CaldroidSampleCustomFragment like example here: https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/blob/master/caldroidSampleActivity/src/main/java/com/caldroidsample

1.Create a Event class:

```
public class Event { 
    public int type; 
    public String msg; 
    public Event(int type,String msg) { this.type = type; this.msg = msg; } 
    public String getMsg(){ return this.msg;}
}
```

2. In CaldroidSampleCustomAdapter :

   ```
   protected HashMap < DateTime, Event > events = new HashMap< DateTime,Event >();
   ```
3. In CaldroidSampleCustomFragment add method:

   ```
   private HashMap<String,CalType> getEvents(DateTime startTime,DateTime endTime){ 

   HashMap<String,CalType> events = new HashMap<String,CalType>(); 

   /// get event of databases from startTime to endTime 

   return events; 

    }
   ```
4. In CaldroidSampleCustomFragment edit refreshView method:

   ```
    public void refreshView() {

   // If month and year is not yet initialized, refreshView doesn't do 

   // anything 

   if (month == -1 || year == -1) 
     { 

      return; 

     } 
   refreshMonthTitleTextView(); 

   // Refresh the date grid views 

   for (CaldroidGridAdapter adapter : datePagerAdapters) { 

   // Reset caldroid data 

   adapter.setCaldroidData(getCaldroidData()); 

   // Reset extra data 

   adapter.setExtraData(extraData); 

   // add events 

   ((CaldroidSampleCustomAdapter)adapter).events = events 

   // Refresh view 

   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

       } 

   }
   ```
5. Final, in getView method of CaldroidSampleCustomAdapter add:

   ```
   Event event = this.events.get(dateTime);

   tv1.setText(event.getMsg());
   ```

Comment: your link was dead  :(

Answer (score 0):

caldroid not support Daily events you should build it by your hands.

First, make custom fragment and custom adapter like example here:
https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/blob/master/caldroidSampleActivity/src/main/java/com/caldroidsample

Then, Add the following code:

1. create your own event model class

   ```
   class DailyEvent {

       public String title;

       public DateTime date;
   }
   ```
2. In CaldroidSampleCustomFragment add:

   ```
   protected HashMap<DateTime, DailyEvent> events = new HashMap<DateTime, DailyEvent>();

   public void refreshView() {
   // If month and year is not yet initialized, refreshView doesn't do
   // anything
   if (month == -1 || year == -1) {
       return;
   }

   refreshMonthTitleTextView();

   // Refresh the date grid views
   for (CaldroidGridAdapter adapter : datePagerAdapters) {
       // Reset caldroid data
       adapter.setCaldroidData(getCaldroidData());

       // Reset extra data
       adapter.setExtraData(extraData);

       // reset events
       adapter.events = events

       // Refresh view
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   }
   ```
3. in CaldroidSampleCustomAdapter add:

   ```
    protected HashMap<DateTime, DailyEvent> events = new HashMap<DateTime, DailyEvent>();
   ```
4. in CaldroidSampleCustomAdapter add to method getView

   ```
   if (events.containsKey(dateTime)) {
               DailyEvent event = events.get(dateTime);
               // do whatever you want with cellView
           }
   ```

Comment: Would you like to elaborate?

Comment: Yes please do elaborate.What do i do after extending the caldroid fragment and listener?

Comment: sorry, What you mean by "custom event"
is it a programming event or it's a day event ?!

Comment: @AbdulrazakAlkl Day-event please :)

Comment: getting errors on this code.
Protected events are not accessible.
Could you post a sample project on github?

Comment: I did exactly same steps.. working fine but when i called adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); then in GetView method in adapter returns dateTime May 2016 dates instead of current month dates (i.e. June 2016) so am unable to show events of current month